# Efficient Repeated calling of NDRangeKernel in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I've written the following code. I have a loop which iterates between two red and black kernels. In each iteration I call clEnqueueReadBuffer which I think is not efficient. Is there any other way to repeat calling kernels efficiently?
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <ocl

Utils.h>

#ifdef MAC
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif


#define DATA_SIZE (1048576)
#define NANO_TO_MILI 1e6
#define MAX_ITER 1
#define LIMIT 100
#define BIG_RANGE LIMIT*4*100

#define EPS 1e-2
#define SQ 1024

#define A(i,j) A[i*SQ+j]

using namespace std;

cl_platform_id platforms;
cl_device_id device;
cl_context context;
cl_program program1, program2;
cl_command_queue command;
cl_int err;
cl_kernel kernel_red, kernel_black;
cl_int i;
cl_mem input_A,input_b,in_out_X;
cl_event timing_event;
cl_ulong time_start, time_end,total_time = 0;


const char options[] = "-cl-mad-enable -cl-finite-math-only -Werror -DWIDTH=1024 -DHEIGHT=1024";
char *kernel_names[] = {"Red","Black"};

float norm (float*,float*,int);
void swap(float **in, float **out); 

void CreateQueue(void);
void CreateKernel(void);
void CreateBuffer(unsigned int);
void Enqueue_Write_Buffer(unsigned int);
void Kernel_Arg_Set(cl_kernel, unsigned int);
void Enqueue_Read_Buffer(unsigned int);
void Create_Work_Group(cl_kernel, unsigned int);
void Shutdown();

float *A,*oldX,*newX,*b;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
unsigned int count = DATA_SIZE;
int i,j;
clock_t start,end;
float *XX,*XXnew;

    A = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*count);
    newX = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*SQ);
    oldX = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*SQ);
    b = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*SQ);

    XX = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*SQ);

    float h=1.0f/SQ;
    float xx[SQ];

    for (i=0;i<SQ;i++){
        XX[i] = 0.0f;
        oldX[i]=0.0f;
        xx[i] = 0.0f + (i+1)*h;
        if (i != 0) b[i] = -2.0f*xx[i]; else b[i] = -2.0f*xx[i]-1.0f/(h*h)+1.0f/(2.0f*h);
        for(j=0;j<SQ;j++) A(i,j) =0.0f;
        A(i,i) = -2.0f/(h*h);
        if (i!=SQ-1) A(i,i+1) = 1.0f/(h*h) + 1.0f/(2.0f*h); else A(i,i+1) = 0.0f;
        if (i != 0)  A(i,i-1) = 1.0f/(h*h) - 1.0f/(2.0f*h); else A(i,i-1) = 0.0f;
    }


    newX[0] = BIG_RANGE;

    int cnt = 0;

    CreateQueue();

    CreateKernel();

    CreateBuffer(count);



    Kernel_Arg_Set(kernel_red  ,count);
    Kernel_Arg_Set(kernel_black,count);

    end=0.0f;start =clock();cnt =0;

    Enqueue_Write_Buffer(count);


    while(norm(oldX,newX,SQ) > EPS && cnt<LIMIT){

    Create_Work_Group(kernel_red, count);

    Enqueue_Read_Buffer(count);

    Create_Work_Group(kernel_black, count);

    cnt++;

    Enqueue_Read_Buffer(count);

    }

    clFinish(command);

    Shutdown();


    free(oldX);
    free(newX);
    free(XX);
    free(XXnew);
    return 0;
}




void CreateQueue(){
err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platforms, NULL);
if(err<0){
    perror("no platform");getchar();exit(1);}

err = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device,NULL);
if(err<0){
    perror("no device");getchar();exit(1);}

context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device,NULL, NULL, &err);
if(err < 0) {
    perror("Couldn't create a context");exit(1);}

command = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &err);
    if (!command)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a command commands!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

clEnqueueBarrier(command);


}

void CreateBuffer(unsigned int count){

    input_A  = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float) * count, A, NULL);
    in_out_X = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE| CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float) * SQ, oldX, NULL);
    input_b  = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float) * SQ, b, NULL);

    if (!input_A || !input_b || !in_out_X)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to allocate device memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }    
}


void CreateKernel(){

    FILE *fp;
    size_t program_size;
    string kernel_src;
    fp = fopen("Red.cl", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    program_size = ftell(fp);
    kernel_src.resize(program_size + 1);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&kernel_src[0], program_size, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    kernel_src[program_size] = '\0';


const char *src = &kernel_src[0];
program1 = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,&src, NULL, &err);

if (!program1)
   {
      printf("clCreateProgramWithSource failed\n");
      exit(1);
   }

err =clBuildProgram(program1, 1, &device, options, NULL, NULL);

if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        size_t len;
        char buffer[2*2048];

        printf("Error: Failed to build program executable!\n");
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program1, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, &len);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        exit(1);
    }



kernel_red   = clCreateKernel(program1, kernel_names[0], &err);

if (!kernel_red || err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create compute kernel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }


kernel_black   = clCreateKernel(program1, kernel_names[1], &err);

if (!kernel_black || err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create compute kernel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

}

void Create_Work_Group(cl_kernel kernel, unsigned int count){

    size_t global[] = {SQ,SQ,0};
    size_t local[] = {32,32,0};
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command, kernel, 2, NULL, global, local, 0, NULL,NULL);
    if (err)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to execute kernel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void Kernel_Arg_Set(cl_kernel kernel,unsigned int count){
    err  = 0;
        err  = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &input_A);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &in_out_X);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &input_b);

    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to set kernel arguments! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void Enqueue_Read_Buffer(unsigned int count){   
    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer( command, in_out_X, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * SQ, oldX, 0, NULL, NULL );  
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to read output array! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void Enqueue_Write_Buffer(unsigned int count){
     err  = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command, input_A , CL_FALSE, 0, sizeof(float) * count,   A, 0, NULL,  NULL);
     err |= clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command, input_b , CL_FALSE, 0, sizeof(float) * SQ   ,   b, 0, NULL,  NULL);
     err |= clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command, in_out_X, CL_FALSE, 0, sizeof(float) * SQ   ,oldX, 0, NULL,  NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to write to source array!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is quite inefficient. You can write the buffer only once, then enqueue as many kernels as you want, with the same buffer as their argument. Of course if you need to compute the norm, you need to read data back. I would suggest something like this:

1. Create an additional buffer for the norm; check at the beginning of every kernel what the norm is (just by reading its value); if it is smaller than threshold value, return immediately.
2. Create a new kernel which will compute the norm for you.
3. Enque tasks like:

   - write buffers,
   - kernels: { {red,black}*10, updateNorm}*10
   - read buffers.

   The computation will run 10x, then norm will be updated. In case it is already ok, already enqueued computation kernels will be will retrun immediately. After the queue is finished, read buffers back and check norm on the CPU. If the norm is still not OK, enqueue the same batch of kernels again.

   In the worst case, you will waste 9 real and 90 immediately returning kernel runs.